# How likely is it that a ternary cometary object forms from a binary one?

Tags: comet, 2014-mu69

Binary comets, like 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko and MU69 Ultima Thule and at least a couple of others, have been observed. How likely would it be for a binary comet to again join with another object to form a trinary comet, i.e. three comets stuck together?

Could such non-destructive slow merger of comets explain extreme elongation such as that of the interstellar object 1I/Oumuamua? It might've been around for longer than the age of the Solar System, having time for more unlikely events. Is there a feasible process that lines up more than two bodies together?

Comment: It's a little early to assume Ultima Thule is a comet, is it not? The composition and presence/absence of a coma are not yet known.

Comment: @called2voyage Okay, nomenclature here. It is certainly a proto-comet. It would form a coma if it came close enough to the Sun. Kuiper Belt objects are comets as far as I'm concerned. 69/P doesn't cease to be a comet when it is too far away to have a coma.

Comment: Again, the composition is not known. We might assume based on other Kuiper Belt objects that it is icy enough to be a comet, but we don't have data for that yet, do we?

Comment: @called2voyage How much do you bet?

Comment: I'm not betting against an icy composition, just saying it would be prudent to put a footnote on that, right?

Comment: I remember you were not originally so excited about moving your last Astronomy question to Astronomy SE, but once you did it was [very well received](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28513/7982) but unfortunately it hasn't been answered yet, so I can't advise you to move this as well (though I would otherwise). Still, I think that to be a Space Exploration question, you might adjust it to ask for the probability that a ternary comet *be observed* rather than form over billions of years.

Comment: @called2voyage zephyr's [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19973/7982) to *Do astronomers generally agree that the distinction between comets and astroids is not so clear?* points out the "state of the art" in figuring out what is or isn't. ;-) You could know everything you want about a body and still not be able to say if it's a comet or not.

Comment: @uhoh True, I just think calling it a "comet" without qualifier is unnecessary for the question and untechnical.

Comment: The probability per unit time of a single object joining a binary would be similar to that of two single objects joining. But I guess you are asking what is the current distribution of singles, binaries, trinaries, ... .

Comment: Elongated asteroids like Itokawa, Eros and others are most probably several big bodies in contact, covered by regolith. I suppose they are elongated (not clumped compactly by gravity) because of rotation. Because elongated objects make up significant amount of observed asteroids/comets, we can suppose "ternary" and more complex systems should not be rare. But there is some problem if masses of bodies are similar - at collision the momentum will be tranfered most efficiently, like in Newton's cradle. So if masses are close, there is more probable some of contact parts will be ejected.

Comment: 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko may consist of a lot more than only two separate bolders, some hundreds to some thousands, we don't know.